# How to position two display: table-cell elements inside a position: fixed div

Tags: html, positioning, css, css-tables

I'm trying to have two alongside divs inside a position fixed parent div, I tried any kind of operation I knew to come to a solution but with no success.
I tried with `display: inline-block`, I tried with `floats` and last with `display: table-cell` but nothing works.
I hope someone of you could come to a solution, thanks in advance.
I'll leave the link to the JSFiddle I used to make some experiments so you can try by yourself:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzN4f/)

```
.CR_FE_MenuB{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(194,194,194,1);
z-index: 10000;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: left;
display: inline-table;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB .CR_FE_Menu_Logo{
width: 20%;
height: 60px;
padding-left: 5%;
display: table-cell;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB .CR_FE_Cont_Menu{
display: table-cell;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB a{
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
color: #008EC8;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB a:hover{
color: #FFF;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB li{
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 19px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.CR_FE_MenuB li:hover{
background-color: #008EC8;
}

.selected{
background-color: #008EC8;
}

.selected a{
color: #FFF;
}
```

G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add vertical-align: bottom to your logo div.

Add the following CSS code -

```
.CR_FE_Menu_Logo{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still cant understand why the div has his 'height' over 6px the one written in the CSS (and the image is 154x60px)
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzN4f/1/)

Comment: No issues, set height to .CR_FE_MenuB as 60px.

Comment: LOL, thanks I feel a little like an idiot with 8 years of web design on my back!